# Ingestion Streaming data with Autoloader using event grid into databricks

Tags: azure-databricks

I have started using a device to load the data into event hub and now I want to ingest the data using auto loader and event grid into databricks. Please help me how can I acheive this.

I have event grid subscription but I need to connect to databricks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few set-up steps that are required for Auto Loader cloudifies to work effectively.

Go to the active directory register the new application .you will need the client id and tenant id and client secret of the new application.

Once you finish app registration navigate to Certificates & secrets and create a new client secret.

[image]

Go to the storage account navigate to Access Control (IAM)  add a new role assignment(contributor) to the provisory register app.

Configuring **Auto loader** in azure data bricks. Follow this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kNG-5uRY4o8) it has a detailed explanation about read and write **streaming data** on the  **Azure Databricks**.